# How do I copy apk file to my sd card through code?

Tags: android, backup, apk, sd-card

I want to create an application similar to "App backup and restore" which stores the apk file from /data/app to the sdcard, and then reinstalls it when we choose to restore.

How can this be done?

Comment: Please don't put tags into subject, especially not highlighted.

Comment: Root the device, then use standard java file IO

Comment: Sorry about the tags, Also I am sure this is possible on a non-rooted phone as well. Anyone knows?